# I need explaination of the following tcl code in ns2

Tags: encryption, tcl, procedure, packet, ns2

```
proc two_ack_app {$source,$destination,$length,$Pkt_sent,$Pkt_loss,$length,$hash_key,$s_time,$w_time,$a_time}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an incomplete call of `proc` with a *very* strange formal parameter name (it's legal to have `$` in the name of a variable, but loopy). It looks like it was half-converted from another language, and it definitely won't work like that (no procedure body!) or be anythin like idiomatic.

I'd expect it really to be written like:

```
proc two_ack_app {source destination length Pkt_sent Pkt_loss length hash_key s_time w_time a_time} {
    # More stuff in here…
}
```